# timout error starting mysql after changing ft_stopword_file setting

Tags: mysql, stop-words

I want to turn off stopwords, and updated my my.cnf file to include:

```
ft_stopword_file=""
```

However, now I get a timeout error when restarting mysql.  If I erase `ft_stopword_file=""`, the error goes away.

Am I getting the syntax wrong, or does the timeout need to be increased for the new setting.  If increased, where is that set?

Comment: What do you mean that it's timing out?  Where are you seeing such an error?

Comment: via SSH - after changing the my.cnf file, you have to restart mysql, and upon mysqld restart, Im given that error.